# this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable function and none was found

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I am trying to use a range-based for loop in a code i am writing. Loops range is based on 2 input taken by a user.

But my code doesn't compile and it gives error:

> "this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable function and none was found".

Is there anyway to fix this problem or should i use something other than range-based for loop ? I should specify that i am not familiar with pointers nor classes.

Shortened version of my code :

```
cin >> rangestart>> rangeend;
int val{ rangestart };
for (auto val : rangeend)
{
    vec.push_back(val);
}
```

Comment: The [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) works on *iterators*, so you need something have can be iterated using iterators for it to work.

Comment: It also works on arrays, but those can be iterated using pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The comments section works on _comments_, so you need something like an answer section for answers to work

Comment: @MSalters Because pointers are iterators

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The obvious way is to use `for (int val = rangestart; val <= rangeend; ++val)`.

The range-based for loop is used to iterate over *collections*. As such, it's inappropriate for your particular use case.

Comment: Thank you. I have little familiarity with Matlab, and i thought range-based for loops works like Matlabs colon operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (auto val : rangeend)
```

This does not mean "iterate from `val` to `rangeend`".

It means "iterate over the collection `rangeend`, with each element being re-declared as `auto val`".

The two things are completely different.

Just use a normal loop with your integer.

Comment: Thank you. I have little familiarity with Matlab, and i thought range-based for loops works like Matlabs colon operator.

Comment: @Vulryn It's best not to guess, but instead to look up the feature to find out how it works and what it does. Matlab and C++ are completely and entirely unrelated.